# Extract data from Nested Arrays of JSON file into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have a Json file that is arrays containing arrays
I can get all "parts" with with code below but unable to figure out the json_normalize parms usage to extract different levels within nested arrays?

ie want 'id' from vehicle array with 'id' from model array with all parts array

```
car | camry | "value":"engine","price":10.82
```

Thanks

```
f = open('sample.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
df1 = json_normalize(data['vehicle'], 'model')
df2 = df1[['parts']]
ddf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['value','charge'])

for (index,row) in df2.iterrows():
    if pd.notnull(row[0]):
        e = row[0]
        ddf.loc[index] = [e[0]['value'], e[0]['charge']]


{
"vehicle":[
{
 "id":"car",
 "model":[
{
  "id":"camry",
"parts": [
{
"value":"engine",
"charge":10.82
}   ]    }
,
{
  "id":"avelon",
"parts": [
{
"value":"seats",
"charge":538.26
}    ]    }
,
{
  "id":"prius",

"parts": [
{
"value":"seats",
"charge":10.91
}    ]    }
,
{
  "id":"corolla",
  "markup": {
  "value":"61"
}
,
  "accessories": [
{
  "value":"vvvvv"
  }]

}    ]    }    ]    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
#remove NaNs
s = df1['parts'].dropna()
#create new DataFrame, assuming only one list always
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s.str[0].values.tolist(), index=s.index)
print (df2)
   charge   value
0   10.82  engine
1  538.26   seats
2   10.91   seats

#join to original
df = df1[['id']].join(df2)
print (df)
        id  charge   value
0    camry   10.82  engine
1   avelon  538.26   seats
2    prius   10.91   seats
3  corolla     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks - followup - what would be the way to handle if "parts" array had multiple parts - ie camry has engine and seats ?

Comment: Do you think `[
{
"value":"engine",
"charge":10.82
} ,{
"value":"engine1",
"charge":9.43} ]` ?

Comment: It depends what need - another pairs of columns? But then get NaNs rows for another rows if length is different of list of dicts. Or need something else?

Comment: Yes - I tried with [ { "value":"engine", "charge":10.82 } ,{ "value":"engine1", "charge":9.43} ] and only 1 is returned

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in solution. So what do you need? new columns? What is desired ouptut if `[ { "value":"engine", "charge":10.82 } ,{ "value":"engine1", "charge":9.43} ]` ?

Comment: Sorry it would be mutiple rows parent with all children ie camry   10.82  engine |   camry  538.26   seats